# Spring Data JPA Fetching data based on a timestamp column

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

How do i retrieve data from a table using spring data JPA on a column that has a timestamp type. Database is mySQL

Column Definition

```
last_update timestamp
```

Domain Object

```
public class Film implements Serializable {
    @Column(name="last_update")
    private Timestamp lastUpdate;

    public Timestamp getLastUpdate() {
        return this.lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdate(Timestamp lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }
}
```

Spring Data JPA Code

```
@Repository                                                        
public interface FilmRepository extends CrudRepository<Film, Integer> 
{
    Film findByLastUpdate(Date date);
}
```

Service Class

```
@Override
public Film readFilmbyDate(){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Film film=null;
    try {
        film= filmRepository.findByLastUpdate(sdf.parse(sdf.format(new Date())));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return film;
}
```

This always returns `null` as the DB column has a `timestamp(2017-05-07 06:45:19)`, basically I want to return all records that have the last updated date to be today / current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method to [`findByLastUpdateBetween(Date date, Date after)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) and pass in the beginning and the end of the date you are looking for. If you are on java 8 you can add a default method to create the dates from one input date and call `findLastUpdateBetween`, otherwise, you can use a [custom implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour) for that.

Comment: thanks Jens, it worked i assume this is the only way for timestamp columns, i cannot use the equal directly

Comment: With a timestamp, you have to use a range query. If read performance is critical you could introduce an additional date column, possibly supported by a functional index (don't know if MySQL has something like this)